# WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('term') is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I used wildcards for the query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%$term%'");
```

and it gives me the results. 
but when I use

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM products WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('$term')");
```

it does not show me any.
Why is that ?

Comment: Could you try to do a direct query through `mysql` and see if that gives any results? Also, try a direct lookup like `name = 'Smd Strip Daylight Led 100cm'`?

Comment: Try adding an `or die (mysql_error());` to your `mysql_query` lines.

Comment: As Mike sugested, add checking in all code that can go wrong (like mysql query calls or file openings). Right now, we could have a thousand questions. Is the filename correct? Is it opened? Does connecting to the database fail or not? Do you connect to the correct database? Do the INSERTs work?

Comment: I have tried it directly through mysql and returned me zero. With the update in my question, as I said, changing the query to search with wildcards it returns me the correct ids so there is no filename, database issue.

Comment: @Nikolai: Ah ok, i missed reading that part of your question. So, `WHERE name LIKE '%strip%'` works but `WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('strip')` doesn't, this is the issue.

Comment: Exaxtly. I guess there must be something with the database, but the mysql_error didn't return me something because name is FULLTEXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is only one product, you might run into the 50% threshold:

> In addition, words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are
>   considered common and do not match. Full-text searches are natural
>   language searches if no modifier is given.

[Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: You gotta be kidding me. Thanks!

Comment: You can test that assumption using `IN BOOLEAN MODE`. It has no 50% threshold.